# How to calculate this value of Sine?

Tags: calculus

So I'm studying for an exam right now and I've got this in one of the practice tests.
[image: practice]

Now my question isn't about how to proceed with this, but about the calculation shown in the second image.
[image: solution]

As you can see we've got $-1/2$ on one side, which then they make into $\sin(-\frac{1}{6}\pi)$.

How do you do that? I'll be doing the exam using a scientific calculator only, so I can't use the tables with all the trig values, etc. I need to know how to do it by hand. (calculating $\sin^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2})$ does give me the decimal value of $-\frac{1}{6}\pi$ but I can't use that...)

Comment: Note that $-\frac{1}{2}=\sin(-\frac{\pi}{6})$. Another way of solving for $x$, is taking the $\arcsin(\dots)$ of both sides, you just have to be careful about the domain.

Comment: Study unit circle, you really need to memorize values of sine and cosine for a few angles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg

Comment: @Vasya , so there is no actual way of calculating it by hand then? Just memorization?

Comment: @TomHimler Could you elaborate? I don't get it.

Comment: Since $\arcsin(x)$ is the inverse of $\sin(x)$ on $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ for $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$. Since the question asks for $0<x<2\pi$ you have to be careful using $\arcsin(x)$. So it's better to find the inverse of $\sin(x)$ by asking yourself (in this case), "where does $\sin(x)$ equal $-\frac{1}{2}$."

Comment: @TomHimler I mean, yeah. But is there a way to do that with simple calculation (and getting pi/6) or is it as Vasya suggested - to memorize the unit circle?

Comment: Well, rather than "calculating it by hand" or "memorization" most people would use a calculator or computer (or us old guys look it up in a table of math functions).    As far as what Tom Himler said, the function "arcsin"  is the inverse function to sin(x)- if y= sin(x) then x= arcsin(y).  One complication is that sin is not "one-to-one" so doesm

Comment: There are ways of learning how to derive those numbers. I recommend looking up information on $30-60-90$ triangles and $45-45-90$ triangles. Each of those have ratio each of their sides have. Through that you can prove the values of the trig functions that you would like by using the fact we're working with the unit circle and the Pythagorean theorem. If you want to be quick solving these question it will be faster to memorize these special values than reproving the values every time.

Comment: @Ivan: yes, we can calculate it by hand using Pythagorean theorem, some trig identities and knowing that leg opposite 30 degree angle is half of a hypotenuse. But I recommend memorizing because you will use these quite often

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle for the sine value $\frac12$ has the hypotenuse $1$ and the side opposite the angle $\frac12$. It is the half of an equilateral triangle, thus the angle has to be $30°=\frac\pi6$. Now apply the symmetries of the sine to deal with the sign.

You should know the associations of the values $0,1,\frac12,\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt3}2$ to the corresponding angle arguments in sine and cosine. There is some memorization rule that puts these values in the common form $\frac{\sqrt{k}}2$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$ with the angles $0°,30°,45°,60°,90°$ for the sine.